# Mysql Query is not working and Apache port goes too high

Tags: mysql, mysqli-multi-query

This query is not working in xampp PMA:

```
SELECT `wp_posts`.`post_title`,`wp_terms`.`name`,`wp_terms`.`term_id`,`wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy`
    FROM `wp_posts`,`wp_terms`,`wp_term_taxonomy`,`wp_term_relationships` 
    WHERE `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` = `wp_posts`.`ID` AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish' AND `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'stores'
```

Comment: i doubt you are correcly joining the tables. You should use proper `INNER JOIN ... ON ...` instead the comma join syntax what is over 25 years old and very hard to read and maintain.

Comment: sir actually i have data base of wordpress and i am trying to fetch the data of stores only

Comment: What does `mysqli_multi_query()` have to do with this? You're only executing one query, and there's no PHP code here.

Comment: @Sultan You need to specify the joining relationships between all 4 tables. You only have the relationship between `wp_term_relationshups` and `wp_posts`, not the rest. So you're getting a huge cross product.

Comment: sorry sir i have no idea of this site i am a new fly in this site so sorry for that if you hav a answer for this than please help

Comment: thanx for a quick reply now let me check your solutuon @barmar

Comment: Like i said @Barmar the topicstarter should use proper INNER JOIN syntax..